# accessing views from a custom title bar in a thread causing null exceptions

Tags: android

i have this fatty fat upload i do (relative to mobile devices). i do this in a thread so that the rest of the device is accessible. in that thread i am accessing a view inside of my custom title. here is the thread:

```
    private OnClickListener send = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        _showView(R.id.progressBar1, true);
        AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
                new BasicAWSCredentials("abc",
                        "123"));

        for(Video v : video.getVideos()) {
            s3.putObject(
                    "bucket",
                    "remote_path"
                    new File("some_file");
        }
        _showView(R.id.progressBar1, false);
    }

}).start();
        }
    };


    private void _showView(int resourceId, boolean show) {
        if (show) {
            findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

how can i access the views of the custom title bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing like this method..

```
_showView(R.id.progressBar1, true);
```

which tries to change UI Should be done using a handler or runOnUiThread.. only main thread can access UI changes..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate views on a non UI thread. Either use view's **post** method or activity's **runOnUiThread** method to do your stuff on views.

For example:

```
private void _showView(int resourceId, boolean show) {

        YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (show) {
                    findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: or use an AsyncTask and do your UI stuff in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(Result).

Answer (score 1):

you should do this..

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
       _showView();

    }

 });



 private void _showView(int resourceId, boolean show) {
                if (show) {
                    findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    findViewById(resourceId).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
  }
```

Any kind of UI is by default handled by UI thread.. if try to modify them in any other thread it causes Exception... You can also use Handlers

```
new Handler().post(
    new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
            _showView();

            }

     }
 );
```